# (Javascript) How to convert a file/bunch of code into a variable?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a helloworld.js and a test.js file. In the test.js file, I want to make a const:

`const helloworldFile = *contents of helloworld.js* file.`

How would I do so?

For example, content of helloworld.js is:

`console.log(1+1)`

how to make

`const helloworldFile = console.log(1+1)`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Seems like maybe an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/193656). Also, what environment are you in? Browser, Node, etc...

Comment: I want to parse a solidity contract file into the constant and use it for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function in one file you want to use elsewhere you can export it from that file like this:

```
export const someFunction = () => console.log(1 + 1)
```

and import it into another file, at the top, like this:

```
import { someFunction } from './helloworld.js' // or whatever the relative path to the file is
```

Then you can use that function anywhere in that file.
Is that kind of what you're looking to do?

Comment: HI yes this is what im looking for. How about for example a text file (non js file) how do i import the entire content into a single const? Thanks!